# Keep vboxadd-service running on a guest vm without syncing the time with the host?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-plugin

The `vboxadd-service` in my VirtualBox guests has to be running to obtain an ip from the following `VagrantFile` code snippet, or else the `vagrant hostupdater` command won't work as expected:

```
  config.hostmanager.ip_resolver = proc do |vm, resolving_vm|
      if vm.id
         `VBoxManage guestproperty get #{vm.id} "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/2/V4/IP"`.split()[1]
      end
  end
```

Resulting `/etc/hosts` file when `vboxadd-service` is turned off:

```
## vagrant-hostmanager-start                                                                            

value   bareOSdirector

value   webserver

value   bareOSremoteSD

## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

And this is because...

If the `vboxadd-service` is running...you can run this command and get:

```
VBoxManage guestproperty get "turnkey_lamp_packer_test_webserver_1502906374188_41719" "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/2/V4/IP"
Value: 10.0.3.8
```

But if it is not running instead you'll get:

```
VBoxManage guestproperty get "turnkey_lamp_packer_test_webserver_1502906374188_41719" "/VirtualBox/GuestInfo/Net/2/V4/IP"
No value set!
```

But in order for me to be able to easily change the time across my VMs for testing things out...the `vboxadd-service` has to NOT be running on a guest vm, or else the time will sync with the host machine when I change it using the `sudo date -s` command.

How can one keep the `vboxadd-service` running while ignoring the time sync, apart from starting and stopping the service every time?  Is there a way to keep the service running without syncing the time with the host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
# On the host...
VBoxManage setextradata "vm-name" "/VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1
```

---

```
# On the guest(s)...
sudo sed -i.bak 's/\(daemon \$binary\) \(--pidfile \$PIDFILE > \/dev\/null\)/\1 --disable-timesync \2/g' /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.0.40/init/vboxadd-service && rm /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.0.40/init/vboxadd-service.bak
sudo sed -i.bak '0,/start-stop-daemon --start --exec \$1 -- \$2 \$3/{s/start-stop-daemon --start --exec \$1 -- \$2 \$3/\0 $4/}'  /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.0.40/init/vboxadd-service && rm /opt/VBoxGuestAdditions-5.0.40/init/vboxadd-service.bak 
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart vboxadd-service
sudo rm /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-timesyncd.service
```